# How do I get my script to loop and quit on command?

Tags: c, loops, pointers, math

I have a basic script but I cant figure out how to get it to loop with an option of ending the script through a key word "quit."

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<math.h>
 #include<string.h>

 int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while(0!=b) { int r = a % b; a=b; b=r; }
    return a;
}
 int input(char* prompt) {
    int res;
    printf("%s: ", prompt);
    scanf("%d", &res);
    return res;
}
 main()
 {
    int add,sub,mul,dd;
    int add1,sub1,mul1,dd1;
    int a,b,c,d;
    a=input("Please enter the numerator for your first equation");
    b=input("Please enter the denominator for your first equation");
    c=input("Please enter the numerator for your second equation");
    d=input("Please enter the denominator for your second equation");
    add=(a*d+b*c);
    add1=(b*d);
    int fac = gcd(add, add1);
        add /=fac;
        add1 /=fac;
    printf("\The sum of your fractions is: %d/%d",add,add1);
    sub=(a*d-b*c);
    sub1=(b*d);
    int red = gcd(sub, sub1);
        sub /=red;
        sub1 /=red;
    printf("\nThe difference of your fractions is: %d/%d",sub,sub1);
    mul=(a*c);
    mul1=(b*d);
    int red1 = gcd(mul, mul1);
        mul /=red1;
        mul1 /=red1;
    printf("\nThe product of your fractions is: %d/%d",mul,mul1);
    dd=(a*d);
    dd1=(b*c);
    int red2 = gcd(dd, dd1);
        dd /=red2;
        dd1 /=red2;
    printf("\nThe quotient of your fractions is: %d/%d",dd,dd1);
 }
```

The idea is to give the user the ability to continuously try the function even after a set of results are given. With that being said, the user should be able to type "quit" in the first numerator question and the script will end. Can someone help me out with that?

**Update 4:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#define LINE_SIZE 100
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while(0!=b) { int r = a % b; a=b; b=r; }
    return a;
}
int input(char* prompt) {
    int res;
   char line[LINE_SIZE];

   printf("%s: ", prompt);
   if ( fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, stdin) == NULL )
   {

      exit(0);
   }

   if (strncmp(line, "quit", 4) == 0 )
   {
      exit(0);
   }

   if ( sscanf(line, "%d", &res) != 1 )
   {
   }

   return res;
}
void computeAndPrint()
{
main();
{
    int add,sub,mul,dd;
    int add1,sub1,mul1,dd1;
    int a,b,c,d;
    a=input("Please enter the numerator for your first equation");
    b=input("Please enter the denominator for your first equation");
    c=input("Please enter the numerator for your second equation");
    d=input("Please enter the denominator for your second equation");
    add=(a*d+b*c);
    add1=(b*d);
    int fac = gcd(add, add1);
        add /=fac;
        add1 /=fac;
    printf("\The sum of your fractions is: %d/%d",add,add1);
    sub=(a*d-b*c);
    sub1=(b*d);
    int red = gcd(sub, sub1);
        sub /=red;
        sub1 /=red;
    printf("\nThe difference of your fractions is: %d/%d",sub,sub1);
    mul=(a*c);
    mul1=(b*d);
    int red1 = gcd(mul, mul1);
        mul /=red1;
        mul1 /=red1;
    printf("\nThe product of your fractions is: %d/%d",mul,mul1);
    dd=(a*d);
    dd1=(b*c);
    int red2 = gcd(dd, dd1);
        dd /=red2;
        dd1 /=red2;
    printf("\nThe quotient of your fractions is: %d/%d",dd,dd1);
 printf("\n");
}

int main();
{
   while ( 1 )
   {
      computeAndPrint();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this case you need to read from input using `%s` instead of `%d`, storing the value in an array and then comparing it with "quit", using `strcmp()`. If the word doesn't match, you can convert it to an integer using `atoi`.

Answer (score 2):

When you have the option of entering a number or the string `quit`, it's better to use `fgets` followed by `strcmp` and `sscanf`.

```
// Make LINE_SIZE as large as you need to
#define LINE_SIZE 100

int input(char* prompt) {
   int res;
   char line[LINE_SIZE];

   printf("%s: ", prompt);
   if ( fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, stdin) == NULL )
   {
      // There is no more input
      exit(0);
   }

   if (strncmp(line, "quit", 4) == 0 )
   {
      // The user entered quit
      exit(0);
   }

   // Expect to see a number
   if ( sscanf(line, "%d", &res) != 1 )
   {
      // Deal with the error
   }

   return res;
}
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

1. Move the core of `main` to a helper function.
2. Use a `while` loop in `main`. In the `while` loop, call the helper function.

```
void computeAndPrint()
{
   int add,sub,mul,dd;
   int add1,sub1,mul1,dd1;
   int a,b,c,d;

   printf("\n");
   a=input("Please enter the numerator for your first equation");
   b=input("Please enter the denominator for your first equation");
   c=input("Please enter the numerator for your second equation");
   d=input("Please enter the denominator for your second equation");

   add=(a*d+b*c);
   add1=(b*d);
   int fac = gcd(add, add1);
   add /=fac;
   add1 /=fac;
   printf("\nThe sum of your fractions is: %d/%d",add,add1);

   sub=(a*d-b*c);
   sub1=(b*d);
   int red = gcd(sub, sub1);
   sub /=red;
   sub1 /=red;
   printf("\nThe difference of your fractions is: %d/%d",sub,sub1);

   mul=(a*c);
   mul1=(b*d);
   int red1 = gcd(mul, mul1);
   mul /=red1;
   mul1 /=red1;
   printf("\nThe product of your fractions is: %d/%d",mul,mul1);

   dd=(a*d);
   dd1=(b*c);
   int red2 = gcd(dd, dd1);
   dd /=red2;
   dd1 /=red2;
   printf("\nThe quotient of your fractions is: %d/%d",dd,dd1);

   printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
   while ( 1 )
   {
      computeAndPrint();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AraMod, change your implementation of `input` with the one I provided. Rest of your code can remain as they are.

Comment: @AraMod, you forgot the `{}` after `if ( sscanf(line, "%d", &res) != 1 )`. They are necessary.

Comment: @AraMod, for that to happen, you have to use a `while` loop around the core code in `main`. The way you have written it now, it will stop after the first set of input.

Comment: @AraMod, you put the definition of `computeAndPrint()` inside a `main`. You need to be careful with copy and paste :) :)

Comment: I hope you still have the `input` function. I didn't see it in the your last block of code.

Comment: Remove `main();
{' that you have at the beginning of the `computeAndPrint()`.

Comment: Ive been on this for the past couple hours and cant figure out what I did wrong. Would you mind showing me how its done? @rsahu

Comment: would a getchar benefit me? @rsahu